# How to upload a sql-Dump to a remote db server only with tcp/ip

Tags: php, windows, curl, mariadb

I would like to upload a sql-dump from mariadb to a remote server with php (curl?).

I have tried the following:

```
<?php

$file_name_with_full_path = '/path/file.sql';

if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) { // php 5.5+
  $cFile = curl_file_create($file_name_with_full_path);
} else { // 
  $cFile = '@' . realpath($file_name_with_full_path);
}

$target_url = "server";
$post = array('extra_info' => '123456','file_contents'=> $cFile);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

as an answer I get something like:

> versionInfo-MariaDBrddas2_fafdas_Mmysql_native_password!��#08S01Got
>   packets out of order

does anyone know hot to fix that? I think i might be close...

Comment: @Ahmad Shakib - if you found  Georg Richter's helpful, please upvote and "accept" it :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message you seem to connect via curl directly to the MariaDB server.

Curl doesn't support the MariaDB/MySQL protocol, and the MariaDB server doesn't provide an interface for obtaining (remote) sql-dumps.

What you have to do is:

1. upload the dump file to the remote server (e.g. via ftp)
2. import the dump file on the server with mysql command line client

If you want to do that automatically, you will need a script or cron job on the server, which frequently checks the directory, which contains uploaded dump files.

Comment: Georg is correct.  More specifically, in order to use your mysql dump, you need to be able to *CONNECT* to the MySql database.  Typically, you *CANNOT* do this remotely (for security - a very good reason!)  That means you need to 1) upload your SQL dump to the remote server, then 2) import the dump locally.  Just like he said :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. As it's not feasible to deploy ftps, i copy the tables one by one with a cronjob (php/mariadb), as the mariadb communicatin works between the servers, but unfortunatly not to the point where we can use db replication...